# Dynamically remove properties from api response

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-apps

I have a api whose response is as below 

  "prop1": "SomeValu1",

  "prop2": "SomeValue2",

  "prop3": null,

  "prop4": "SomeValue4"

The problem is, based on input some of the properties will be null(expected behavior) which i don;t want to
  return in the response. Something like this (prop3 is not there)

  "prop1": "SomeValu1",

  "prop2": "SomeValue2",

  "prop4": "SomeValue4"

Which property will be null is based on runtime logic. Any ideas how can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are working on JSON then You can try this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, 
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
                        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataContract` attribute has property called `EmitDefaultValue` if you set it to false it will not be serialized.

If you add those attributes in your Dto class you will get functionality that you are asking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class ExampleDto
{
    [DataMember(Name="prop1", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    [DataMember(Name="prop2", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
    [DataMember(Name="prop3", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Prop3 {get;set;}
    [DataMember(Name="prop4", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Prop4 {get;set;}
}
```

You can even use property `Name` to change it's name when serializing.